# How do I filter an alist to just the properties I care about?

Tags: json, association-lists, filtering

To effectively use a service's API, I'm leveraging `json-read` to turn the JSON response into an understandable data structure:

```
(let ((json-object-type 'alist)
      (json-array-type  'list)
      (json-key-type    'symbol)
      (json-false       nil)
      (json-null        nil))
  (json-read))
```

This works *great*, but gives me a *bunch* of garbage that I don't care about.

I want a function `keep-structure` that works through this alist and filters out all of the junk:

```
(keep-structure '((owner login) name)
                '((owner (login . "octocat") (avatar . "blah"))
                  (name . "Hello-World")
                  (some-url . "https://some-domain")
                  (stars . 42)))

;; => ((owner (login . "octocat"))
       (name . "Hello-World"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursion for the win.

```el
(defun json-filter-paths (json paths)
  (mapcar (lambda (elt)
            (if (consp elt)
                (cons (car elt)
                      (json-filter-paths (cdr (assoc (car elt) json)) (cdr elt)))
              (cons elt (cdr (assoc elt json)))))
          paths))

(json-filter-paths'((owner (login . "octocat") (avatar . "blah")
                           (meta (x . "42") (y . "43")))
                    (name . "Hello-World")
                    (some-url . "https://some-domain")
                    (stars . 42))
                  '(name (owner login (meta x))))
;; ((name . "Hello-World") (owner (login . "octocat") (meta (x . "42"))))
```

Comment: Oooh, that's much nicer-looking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take this for a spin:

```lisp
(require 'dash)  ;; also needs emacs-25 for `if-let'
(defun keep-structure (structure object)
  (let* ((only-tops (mapcar (lambda (el)
                              (if (consp el) (car el) el))
                            structure))
         (top-pass (--filter (memq (car it) only-tops)
                             object)))
    (mapcar
     (lambda (subobj)
       (if-let ((substructure
                 (cdar (--filter (and (consp it)
                                      (eq (car subobj)
                                          (car it)))
                                 structure))))
           (cons (car subobj)
                 (keep-structure substructure (cdr subobj)))
         subobj))
     top-pass)))

(keep-structure '((owner login) name)
                '((owner (login . "octocat") (avatar . "blah"))
                  (name . "Hello-World")
                  (some-url . "https://some-domain")
                  (stars . 42)))
```